# Invalid syntax in sharepoint list filter of power automate action

Tags: filtering, power-automate, sharepoint-list

I have created a small Power Automate flow. It gets triggered by incoming emails and should use the sender's email address to process rows from a sharepoint table. One column of that table has the name "E-Mail". The flow and filter within look like this:

[image: Select sharepoint list elements]

This the error message:

```
The expression "E-Mail eq 'donald.duck@gmail.com'" is invalid. Creating query failed.
clientRequestId: d5371e22-1551-49f3-b539-0ecc3bd1881f
serviceRequestId: d5371e22-1551-49f3-b539-0ecc3bd1881f

{
    "host": {
        "connectionReferenceName": "shared_sharepointonline",
        "operationId": "GetItems"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "dataset": "https://btbgmbh658.sharepoint.com/sites/devtest",
        "table": "810454a5-24fe-477e-b19e-28e3a702ba4f",
        "$filter": "E-Mail eq 'donald.duck@gmail.com'"
    }
}
```

(I am using donald.duck@gmail.com as a placeholder here. The list contains a valid email address and the test email being processed is coming from that address).

The sharepoint list does contain a column named "E-Mail":

[image: E-Mail column description]

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the name of the field in the JSON response? Remove the filter, get a response returned, check the name of the field and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OData filter queries (the Abfragen filtern uses those type of queries) you need to use the internal name of the column, not the displayname.

You can retrieve that internal name in different ways. Try for example the column settings, like described in this article:
https://elliskarim.com/2021/12/20/finding-the-internal-name-of-a-sharepoint-column/#method-1-column-settings